# Is Package logging required if we use SSIS Catalog

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm converting huge number of SSIS packages from Package Deployment model to Project Deployment and using the SSIS Catalog. My old packages have got SSIS logging enabled to log into SQL Server. Do I still need to use package level logging, I found out that SSIS Catalog has got different levels of logging and also helpful Execution Reports. So just wondering what are the advantages of using package level logging or is it something can be ignored now?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The logging in SSIS catalog provides you the option to capture the level of logging like minimum detail to maximum.

**Advantage of Package level logging:**

Log files can be stored in local system and those can be analyzed by anyone (user not having access to the ssis catalog).

**Advantage of SSIS Catalog level logging:**

1. log is organized in step by step in report format.
2. We can query the log tables to analyze something (you can generate your own report).

**Concerns of SSIS Catalog level logging:**

1. To view the logs user must be a member of the `ssis_admin` or `sysadmin` roles (In SQL Server 2016, it has been fixed by addition of a new roles like `ssis_logreader` and `ssis_monitor`). **Or the user who deployed the project can only see the log for those packages**.
2. SSMS is required to view the log reports
3. Cleaning the log records periodically (not a concern but), you have to set your retention window appropriately else log size can grow huge depending upon the level of the logging.

For more info: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231191.aspx) and [Refer](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2015/08/14/ssis-catalog-logging-in-the-enterprise.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, definitely a very helpful answer, Other than the access rights issue I don't see any point in spending extra time to add package logging. In my scenario the user who maintains the packages always has sysadmin rights.